# To make SKU combination in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's just say I have an array with n number of index:

```
0:{prop1: 'abc', prop2: ['1', '2', '3'],
1:{prop1: 'xyz', prop2: ['8', '6']
```

Now, what I am trying to make is a combination like this:

```
(1,8)
(1,6)
(2,8)
(2,6)
(3.8)
(3,6)
```

I have tried multiple methods couldn't achieve this combination

Comment: show your code plz

Answer (score 0):

Check `CartesianProduct` class from package [js-combinatorics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-combinatorics), I think this is the right tool for your task:

```
let it = new CartesianProduct('123','86');
it.length;  // 6
[...it];    /* [
  ['1', '8'],
  ['2', '8'],
  ['3', '8'],
  ['1', '6'],
  ['2', '6'],
  ['3', '6']
] */
```

Comment: instead of writing a few strings of code you prefer loading some lib?

Comment: Yes, I am just like the guy from JS meme who imports `is-odd` NPM package instead of simply writing `x % 2` :D Just kidding. But in this case, I think using a tested library code for combinatorial functions is reasonable.